# What is negative gradient (or whatever this symbol is)

Tags: vector-analysis

Given
$$F=-\nabla_eU(e_n, E_n, p_n)$$
The function U is defined at $U(e_n, E_n, p_n) = p_n  e_n + (E_n - 0.5  e_n)  e_n$

$e_n$, $E_n$, and $p_n$ are all scalar values the system.

In the above equation, I don't understand the context of the negative gradient. Not sure where else to ask so just wondering if someone could explain what those symbols mean here?

Comment: The gradient of a scalar function is a vector field. The negative of the gradient is the vector field with each vector pointing in the opposite direction. It's not really a new concept: it's just the negative of a vector.

Comment: It looks like an equation from physics, where you have a potential $U$ that depends on several quantities, and $F$ is the force

Comment: First of all, thank you for responding to my question! In this problem however, the function $U(e_n, E_n, p_n)$ yields a scalar value. I'm uncertain as to what the vector produced by this is compromised of (read: which variables make up the vector)

Answer (score -1):

$F = -grad(V)$

Negative gradient tells us that the direction of force generated due to this potential is from point with higher potential to point associated with low potential along path with maximum rate of change.